# C++ - How to hide other application's window

Tags: c++, windows, qt, user-interface, logic

I am trying to create a software(Qt/C++). In which I need a functionality that hiding other application windows based on their window titles. Hiding means invisible not minimize. Can any body say how to achieve this?. I am currently working on Windows platform.

Note: If you provide a solution via Qt, it will give more comfort. Because it provides  the platform independency.

Comment: when you say hide do you mean minimize

Answer (score 9):

For Windows, if you have an `HWND` to another application's window, you can call the [`ShowWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, like this:

```
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);
```

You can get an `HWND` to another application's window using the [`FindWindow`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API function.

Interacting with other applications like this is necessarily platform-specific. There is no generic way to do this using Qt, because Qt is a framework for *your* application, not anybody else's.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/QDWndTransparency.aspx) you can find a tutorial on how to make a window transparent on windows.

As mentionied before, you must find the window's handle by it's title using the API.