# How to find handle of unknown window in c++?

Tags: c++, window, handler, pocketpc

I want to find handle of a window whose title may be of type ****.log*** where ***.log** could be **temp.log, dummy.log etc.**

**I dont know the title but i know the extension of log type.**

I know `FindWindow` API is used for finding the handle of the window but there we need to know the title name. So if i dont know anything about the window only knows the extension then how to retrieve the handle for the same using c++?

Comment: Check [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6093062/c-how-to-hide-other-applications-window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for top-level windows and and [GetWindowText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the title.

[PathMatchSpec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773727%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should work for your pattern matching.

GetWindowText makes sure you don't "stall" if the process you are asking is not responding.

Answer (score 1):

Haven't use the WinAPI for years, but if memory serves me, there is an [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function that you use in such a case.